# Measuring laundry load weight to determine right amount of detergent to use

Tags: cleaning, laundry

On my detergent's instructions it says to use x amount of powder per (x)KG of clothes.

While there are a bunch of clothes that will be going into the load, how can i determine the right amount of detergent to use for the load if the instructions indicate a detergent amount per load weight? or can i just use roughly amount of whatever i think is ok?

Comment: I believe the quality of washing depends on the quality of the detergent. This is a variable and I feel benchmark cannot be set for this parameter. It varies for the seasons, climate, temperature, soaking time, earlier packed date of the detergent, pH and salt content of the water, etc.

Comment: It also depends on the amount and the quality / type of the "dirty", e.g. simple dust vs. fats / greases, pigmented stuff, whether the color of the clothes needs to be preserved (usually yes)...

Answer (score 5):

Frankly, I'm surprised your brand expects you to know the *weight* of your laundry to use their product. Every brand I use specifies a fraction of a ***cap-full*** based on the *volume* of the load.

*For example:*

> **Large load:** use a capful
> **Medium load:** use 2/3 capful
> **Small load:** use 1/3 capful

My suggestion is to **use volume instead of weight** to estimate the amount of detergent you need.

#### Estimating the amounts needed by volume

First, fill your washing machine to capacity to determine an average weight<sup>1</sup> of a "full load". Using the cap or measuring cup for your detergent, add the amount of detergent suggested for that weight. Use a permanent marker to place a mark on the measuring cup at that level and label it "full load". Then mark off whatever increments are convenient for that fraction of a load (see the example above).

That will provide a convenient reference so you don't have to weigh your laundry each time. If your laundry is not coming out clean, you can add a bit more. Stained or dirtier laundry may also need a bit more detergent while less soiled loads may need a bit less. Measurements are not typically that precise.

---

*<sub><sup>(1)</sup> To determine the weight of an item without a dedicated freight scale: Weigh yourself with common household body-weight scale while holding the item (e.g. the bag of laundry). Your weight holding the item minus your normal weight (without the item) equals the weight of the item itself.</sub>*

Comment: Great, but without a scale how will i know my weight with holding the laundry basket.

Comment: @Nofel You only need to do this once ever. I would either borrow a scale or go to a friend's house or somewhere where they have one.

Comment: Thanks, and by load. what would it mean, when we say full load, medium or small?

Comment: A "full load" is the most laundry you would add to your washing machine before you feel it would no longer do a good job. A "medium load" is about 2/3rds of that, and a "small load" about 1/3.

Comment: Load is only a part of the math needed; water hardness can halve or double  the required dose. Additionally, a few shirts with a bit of collar grime is a totally different proposition to half a team's football kit after a rainy match. [& btw, I still don't think this needs a life hack, it's pure learning curve/experience/how-to]

Comment: Most top-loading washing machines have a table on the cover with the approximate weight of a full load in both imperial and metric units. So I'm not surprised the detergent s instructions are based on the weight of the load. Not all washing machines are created equal. Some are for heavy loads such as winter bedding or courtains (industrial loads, they call them) some are economy sixed machines that fit under the sink and won't handle more than abdsys worth of clothes for a couple. Most will indicate the weight of maximum load clearly printed near the control knobs or on the cover of the tank.

Answer (score 2):

1. Weigh yourself holding the laundry basket full of clothes.
2. Put the clothes in the washing machine.
3. Weigh yourself holding the empty laundry basket.
4. Subtract the second weight from the first weight.

That will tell you how many kg of clothes you are washing.

(But personally, I would just estimate how much detergent you think it needs, based on how full the washing machine is and how much water you are filling it with.)

Comment: Given the OP's question this is the correct answer! The other questions assume liquid soap (not the case) or what the right instructions should be (they are what they are, right or wrong) I would also add that not all washing machines are created equal. Some handle larger loads, some are compact and only handle light loads. The approximate weight of a full load should be clearly indicated somewhere in the machine, most likely near the control knobs or the cover.

Answer (score 0):

Laundry Load Size Infographics by Rajshree[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to do weigh your bag with travel scales ie suitcase. Then you get it right every time.

Comment: Hi Roger, and welcome to Lifehacks! I'm confused by the phrase "travel scales ie suitcase". Could you edit your question to clarify what you mean? How would the person asking the question be able to weigh each load of laundry, presumably several times a week, using your method?

Comment: Travel scales tend to be very inaccurate for weights below about 10kg.  Very few washing machines can cope with more than about 5kg.